# css-files are partly appplied when building a windows.exe from a a javafx project using j4launch as a wrapper

Tags: css, windows, javafx, exe, wrapper

```
I have a Javafx project developed in eclipse with some css-files for table and chart backgrounds. In eclipse everything works fine, but when I use j4launch to built a windows .exe the css- files is not applied to the tables and (what seems very strange to me) only one of two line charts shows the wanted background. Both line charts refer to the the same css-file bau are situated in different tabs. I am using jre1.8.0_211. Can someone help me? It would be great. Thank you Marcus
```

I checked in scenebuilder that the refered css-files are all in the project. I cleaned and rebuilt the project and tried j4launch again, but the results are the same.

This is the first line in  the project controller.fxml (sa there seam to be issues with the UTF-8:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

This is the css code attached to the barchart:

```
    .chart {
        -fx-padding: 10px;
    }
    .chart-content {
        -fx-padding: 30px;    
    }

     .chart-title {
       -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
       -fx-font-size: 1.6em;
    }

     .axis-label {
       -fx-text-fill: white ;
    }

    .chart-legend {
       -fx-background-color:   #8c9cca;
       -fx-padding: 20px;
    }

    .chart-legend-item-symbol{
       -fx-background-radius: 0;
    }

    .chart-legend-item{
       -fx-text-fill: #ffffff
    }

    .chart-plot-background {
       -fx-background-color: transparent;
    }
    .chart-vertical-grid-lines {
       -fx-stroke: #3278fa;
    }
    .chart-horizontal-grid-lines {
       -fx-stroke: #8c9cca;
    }
    .chart-alternative-row-fill {
       -fx-fill: transparent;
       -fx-stroke: transparent;
       -fx-stroke-width: 0;
    } 

and this is the css for the tables:

    .table-view{
       -fx-background-color: transparent;
    }

    .table-view{
       -fx-border-color: red;
    }

    .table-view:focused{
        -fx-background-color: transparent;
    }

    /* Spaltenköpfe
    Struktur column-header-background -> column-header */

    .table-view .column-header-background{
        -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#131313 0%, #424141 100%);
    }

    .table-view .column-header-background .label{
        -fx-background-color: transparent;
        -fx-text-fill: white;
    }

    .table-view .column-header {
        -fx-text-fill: bisque ;
        -fx-background-color: transparent;
    }

    .table-view .table-cell{
        -fx-text-fill: White;
        -fx-font-size: 14px;
    }

    .table-row-cell{
       -fx-background-color: -fx-table-cell-border-color, #616161;
       -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
       -fx-padding: 0.0em; /* 0 */
    }

    .table-row-cell:odd{
       -fx-background-color: -fx-table-cell-border-color, #424242;
       -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
       -fx-padding: 0.0em; /* 0 */  
    }

    .table-row-cell:selected {
        -fx-background-color:  #CBDAFF;
        -fx-background-insets: 0;
        -fx-background-radius: 1;
        -fx-border-color: #b3c7dc;
    }

    .table-view:focused .table-row-cell:selected .table-cell {
        -fx-text-fill: black;
    }


    .table-view > .virtual-flow > .scroll-bar:vertical,
    .table-view > .virtual-flow > .scroll-bar:vertical > .track,
    .table-view > .virtual-flow > .scroll-bar:vertical > .track-background, 
    .table-view > .virtual-flow > .scroll-bar:horizontal,
    .table-view > .virtual-flow > .scroll-bar:horizontal > .track,
    .table-view > .virtual-flow > .scroll-bar:horizontal > .track-background     
    {             
        -fx-background-color: transparent;
    }



    .table-view > .virtual-flow > .scroll-bar > .increment-button, 
    .table-view > .virtual-flow > .scroll-bar > .decrement-button {
        -fx-opacity: 0;
    }


No error messages. The windows programm is running bit the the stylesheets ara just partly applied (see above).
```

Comment: Show how you are referencing the css to your project

Comment: The references are automatically generated by scenebuilder. Here is a line  from my Project.fxml (the main window) where the css for a table is referenced  :<TableView fx:id="tableMa_KostAbteilung" layoutX="920.0" layoutY="424.0" maxHeight="221.0" prefHeight="221.0" prefWidth="850.0" style="-fx-background-color: #071129;" stylesheets="@../../css/Table.css" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="328.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="920.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="100.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="432.0">